# Visual Basic Program that Requires TryParse

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a larger and smaller program in VisualStudio using VisualBasic. I'm new to coding and I'm unsure of how to add TryParase to my code to make it work. I need it to verify integers are being inputted and display a error message if something other than an integer is entered.

```
Private Sub btnCompare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompare.Click
        Dim number1 As Double
        Dim number2 As Double

        number1 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
        number2 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)

        If number1 < number2 Then
            TextBox3.Text = "Value B is greatest"
        End If
        If number1 > number2 Then
            TextBox3.Text = "Value A is greatest"
        End If
        If number1 = number2 Then
            TextBox3.Text = "Value A and B are the same"
        End If
        If TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number1) Then
            TextBox3.Text = "ERROR: User did not enter an Integer"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: First hint: `TryParse` should *instead of* `Convert.ToDouble`. Second hint: The `If` is reversed, it returns `True` on successful conversion, and `False` with an invalid value.

Comment: Third hint (perhaps follow-up to the first hint): Move the `If` statement that checks the `TryParse` result to happen _before_ the numerical comparisons.  If the integers can't be parsed, the numerical comparisons should be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub btnCompare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompare.Click
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number1) OrElse
       Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, number2) Then
        TextBox3.Text = "ERROR: User did not enter an Integer"            
    ElseIf number1 < number2 Then
        TextBox3.Text = "Value B is greater"
    ElseIf number1 > number2 Then
        TextBox3.Text = "Value A is greater"
    Else
        TextBox3.Text = "Values A and B are the same"
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll note a number of other improvements there too, like using the correct data type i.e. `Integer` rather than `Double`. I assume that that is correct from your error message. I have also corrected your lack of `Else` statements.